How to embed a power bi mobile version in a Flutter webView?
I created a flutter file containing js, following the bi doc and made the webview following the steps in the doc webview_flutter: 4.7.0
However, I can't proceed after this part, I can't display the Bi with the indicated parameters
Importantly, I need to display the bi in mobile mode, the way I found it was using "layoutType: models.LayoutType.MobilePortrait,"
I need to display this link as a webview in portable mode and take the address using the "embedUrl" variable and present it in the iframe
problem presented "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'models')", Did not find frame
I already tried putting the iframe this way too
    "\<iframe title="test mobile" width="1024" height="1060" frameborder="0" 

allowFullScreen="true" src="{{embedUrl}}"\>\</iframe\>"

but it still doesn't make the call, I already tried using flutter_inappwebview 6.0.0 but I also didn't get any different results

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter_android/webview_flutter_android.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter_wkwebview/webview_flutter_wkwebview.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MaterialApp(home: WebViewExample(), debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false));

const String kLocalExamplePage = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test Bi</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="embedContainer">
    <iframe title="test mobile" width="1024" height="1060" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
</div>

  <script>
  let loadedResolve, reportLoaded = new Promise((res, rej) => { loadedResolve = res; });
  let renderedResolve, reportRendered = new Promise((res, rej) => { renderedResolve = res; });

models = window['powerbi-client'].models;

    // Read embed application token
    let accessToken = EMBED_ACCESS_TOKEN;
    
    // Read embed URL
    let embedUrl = 'https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiYzZmM2ViNGEtNzI2OS00YTUyLThjMDUtNTViOWU5ZTAyN2IwIiwidCI6ImM1ZDI4NTZmLWJlOTYtNGQwZi1hY2FiLWZlOTJkZTY2MjhiZCJ9';

    document.querySelector('#embedContainer iframe').src = embedUrl;

    // Read embed type from radio
    let tokenType = TOKEN_TYPE;

    // We give All permissions to demonstrate switching between View and Edit mode and saving report.
    let permissions = models.Permissions.All;

    let config = {
        type: 'report',
        tokenType: tokenType == '0' ? models.TokenType.Aad : models.TokenType.Embed,
        accessToken: accessToken,
        embedUrl: embedUrl,
        id: embedReportId,
        permissions: permissions,
        settings: {
        layoutType: models.LayoutType.MobilePortrait,
        panes: {
          filters: {
            visible: false
          },
          pageNavigation: {
            visible: false
          }
        },
        bars: {
          statusBar: {
            visible: false
          }
        }
      }
    };

    // Get a reference to the embedded report HTML element
    let embedContainer = document.querySelector('#embedContainer')[0];

    // Embed the report and display it within the div container.
    report = powerbi.embed(embedContainer, config);

    // report.off removes all event handlers for a specific event
    report.off("loaded");

    // report.on will add an event handler
    report.on("loaded", function () {
        loadedResolve();
        report.off("loaded");
    });

    // report.off removes all event handlers for a specific event
    report.off("error");

    report.on("error", function (event) {
        console.log(event.detail);
    });

    // report.off removes all event handlers for a specific event
    report.off("rendered");

    // report.on will add an event handler
    report.on("rendered", function () {
        renderedResolve();
        report.off("rendered");
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
''';

class WebViewExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebViewExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<WebViewExample> createState() => _WebViewExampleState();
}

class _WebViewExampleState extends State<WebViewExample> {
  late final WebViewController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // #docregion platform_features
    late final PlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams params;
    if (WebViewPlatform.instance is WebKitWebViewPlatform) {
      params = WebKitWebViewControllerCreationParams(
        allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
        mediaTypesRequiringUserAction: const <PlaybackMediaTypes>{},
      );
    } else {
      params = const PlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams();
    }

    final WebViewController controller = WebViewController.fromPlatformCreationParams(params);
    // #enddocregion platform_features

    controller
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onProgress: (int progress) {
            debugPrint('WebView is loading (progress : $progress%)');
          },
          onPageStarted: (String url) {
            debugPrint('Page started loading: $url');
          },
          onPageFinished: (String url) {
            debugPrint('Page finished loading: $url');
          },
          onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {
            debugPrint('''
Page resource error:
  code: ${error.errorCode}
  description: ${error.description}
  errorType: ${error.errorType}
  isForMainFrame: ${error.isForMainFrame}
          ''');
          },
          onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
            if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
              debugPrint('blocking navigation to ${request.url}');
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            }
            debugPrint('allowing navigation to ${request.url}');
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
          onUrlChange: (UrlChange change) {
            debugPrint('url change to ${change.url}');
          },
        ),
      )
      ..addJavaScriptChannel(
        'Toaster',
        onMessageReceived: (JavaScriptMessage message) {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(content: Text(message.message)),
          );
        },
      )
      ..loadHtmlString(kLocalExamplePage);

    // #docregion platform_features
    if (controller.platform is AndroidWebViewController) {
      AndroidWebViewController.enableDebugging(true);
      (controller.platform as AndroidWebViewController).setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    }
    // #enddocregion platform_features

    _controller = controller;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.green.shade700,
        title: const Text(
          'test Bi',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
      body: WebViewWidget(controller: _controller),
    );
  }
}

